part of ram used by hidden processes in Windows
after some time some hidden processes are using my ram. They are not shown nor in process hacker, nor in system informer.
On attached screenshot on bottom right it shows that 25GB is used in total, but when i open system informer it shows that sum of shown processes is only 20.5GB
sometime this difference can be 10-20GB
i have 64GB ram, this issue was also when i had 32GB.


How much ram do you actually have? That 5GB or so just looks like the difference between the active and committed memory (includes pagefile space). Try using windows Task Manager > Details tab > select columns > "Working set (memory)" and "Commit size"

@Cpt.Whale as i understand committed mem = working set + pagefile.
so my question is why some hidden processes are using my working set.
i have 64GB now

Not necessarily - Commit size (virtual) can be smaller than Working set (physical) for example. Unfortunately, different software can use different terms to describe these stats. There are some common issues with summing up memory usage, as separate compression/standby cache/suspended processes can be split into different stats. If possible, add a screenshot of the Task Manager > Performance tab > Memory section, as well as the Details tab with memory columns
